# Prepositions of Movement with to walk

Tags: prepositions

Original sentence: "There was the last street I needed to walk before reaching the park."

Corrected sentence: "There was one last street I needed to walk down before reaching the park."

Question:  Why do you need the 'down' preposition?  If the reason is just to make it more clear wouldn't the sentence be fine without it?

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions can be combined with verbs in English to form "phrasal verbs."  When they do this, they're really an adverb (or "particle"), not a preposition.

Most common prepositions can also work as these "particles."

In some cases it changes the meaning of the verb entirely, in other cases it's just a form of emphasis or to communicate the idea of "completely" (particularly with *up*).

> I broke the box (The box has sustained damaged and is unusable)
>
> I broke down the box (The box has been taken apart but can still be used if put back together)

*Down* and *up* are often used as these particles with verbs of motion to communicate that the motion happens along the entire length of a distance, such as a street, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The verb 'walk' is used in a surprisingly large number of different ways. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/walk) lists a number of transitive and intransitive usages.

Here,

> *There was one last street I needed to walk down to get to the*
>   *park.*

is ODO's sense 1:

> 1 [no object] usually with adverbial
>
> *I walked across the lawn* / [*I walked down the street.*]

it is the normal unmarked usage.

..............

> *There was one last street I needed to walk.*

doesn't sound idiomatic.

> *He / She / ... / ... walked the streets of Los Angeles.*

is certainly idiomatic, but has one of two marked (different from the normal) senses:

> **walk the streets** [can mean] to walk from one street to another, especially when one is looking for a job (same as pounding the
>   pavement).
>
> [But] if you say for instance that young teenage girls in Vancouver
>   are walking the streets late at night, it means they are soliciting as
>   prostitutes.

[[Marylin_UsingEnglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/13717-walk-the-street-walked-along-the-street)]

As to *why* English works this way ...  you probably won't get a better answer than 'it just does' (or perhaps 'these are the complex ways the language has evolved').